# Grid layout footer breaking on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, grid

Consider:

[image]

[image]

I currently have a 12 col/ 12 row grid layout for my website. It works fine and is responsive when using mobile emulation. The issue is when viewing the website on actual phones, the footer initially positions itself above the address bar, but when the address bar disappears it stays in the same spot and the content overflows past it.

The first picture is how it looks initially.

The second picture is after I scrolled.

Then *html* and *body* are set to 100%, and I tried to use *vh* on the body.

Comment: could you include the images and also a [example]?

Comment: @cornonthecob I added the images.

Comment: @Dave Aigbe Jr.: Asking for more than one thing at a time usually doesn't work.

Comment: That leaves the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use *vh*; use *%*:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html, body {
            min-height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .content {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="content">
        <p>This is some content on my website.</p>
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>© 2023 My Website. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’m limited to using grid for the layout, I would be able to fix the problem if I could switch to flex, but thank you.

Comment: Re *"Don’t use vh; use %"*: There aren't any (literal) "%" in the CSS. What do you mean? Can you elaborate?